# Calculated field based on string value of another column R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe with a column "status" and session

[image][image]

My question is how can I create a for loop that populates the field session with the numbers 1-20 based on the START or STOP value in the other column?

So my result would give something like the following

Status  Session
START   1
STOP    1
START   2
STOP    2
START   3
STOP    3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `DF` be your data frame.

```
## solution 1
DF$Session <- rep(1:(nrow(DF) / 2), each = 2)

## solution 2
DF$Session <- cumsum(DF$Status == "START")
```

Comment: Thanks so much was getting caught up trying to use ifelse to evaluate if it was == START or STOP